# Click Event is not Firing GTM

Tags: events, analytics, google-tag-manager

I created a Trigger Group which contains usual GA Event and the trigger when the user confirms Cookies. In preview mode, by clicking to the needed button only very first click event os tracking. After that, no clicks are tracking. What can be the problem? When the triggers are not in Trigger Group, everything works correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Trigger group has been bugged since introduced. A trigger group can only be triggered once per pageview even if the triggers in the group keep repeating.